# Show used cookies Magento website

Tags: cookie

Is there any way how i can create a list of ALL cookies (incl. 3rd party cookies) which my Magento website is using?

I've searched throughout Magento, searched on Google, searched the forums, but i can't find anything how i can realize this.

Comment: Check the `$_COOKIES` array

Comment: Developers tools either in Chrome/FF should help you too.

Comment: Thank you, worked both for me! I haven't thought about this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FireBug plugin to see all request information or print the $_COOKIES auto global variable as suggested in comments.

Answer (score 3):

Cookie Name --> Information

CART --> The association with your shopping cart.

CATEGORY_INFO --> Stores the category info on the page, that allows to display pages more quickly.

COMPARE --> The items that you have in the Compare Products list.

CURRENCY --> Your preferred currency

CUSTOMER --> An encrypted version of your customer id with the store.

CUSTOMER_AUTH --> An indicator if you are currently logged into the store.

CUSTOMER_INFO --> An encrypted version of the customer group you belong to.

CUSTOMER_SEGMENT_IDS --> Stores the Customer Segment ID

EXTERNAL_NO_CACHE --> A flag, which indicates whether caching is disabled or not.

FRONTEND --> You sesssion ID on the server.

GUEST-VIEW --> Allows guests to edit their orders.

LAST_CATEGORY --> The last category you visited.

LAST_PRODUCT --> The most recent product you have viewed.

NEWMESSAGE --> Indicates whether a new message has been received.

NO_CACHE --> Indicates whether it is allowed to use cache.

PERSISTENT_SHOPPING_CART --> A link to information about your cart and viewing history if you have asked the site.

POLL --> The ID of any polls you have recently voted in.

POLLN --> Information on what polls you have voted on.

RECENTLYCOMPARED --> The items that you have recently compared.

STF --> Information on products you have emailed to friends.

STORE --> The store view or language you have selected.

USER_ALLOWED_SAVE_COOKIE --> Indicates whether a customer allowed to use cookies.

VIEWED_PRODUCT_IDS --> The products that you have recently viewed.

WISHLIST --> An encrypted list of products added to your Wishlist.

WISHLIST_CNT --> The number of items in your Wishlist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of the default magento 2 cookies which will help everyone who want to meet GDPR requirements - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/cookie-reference.html