# How to see cookies name in magento websites

Tags: cookie

I found this link, [Show used cookies Magento website](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32142/show-used-cookies-magento-website)

how to see the cookies we use

Answer (score 0):

you can list all cookies ,

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $key.' is '.$val."<br>\n";
}
```